# What's the best way to make sure external URLs aren't interpreted as relative links?

Tags: templating

I have a field where the client can enter a URL, and then that field's value is put into the 'href' of a link in the template. The client will sometimes prepend it with "http://", sometimes with "www.", and sometimes with nothing. Unless it's prepended with "http://" or "https://", the link is interpreted as relative and tries to go to "http://mysite.com/www.otherlink.com", which is obviously not what I want.

What's the best way of automatically handling different URL formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Craft, you could go two ways:

1. Make your own field-type, that handles the url in PHP and appends http:// if needed ([Create a plugin for that](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types))
2. Check the url for 'http' in your template, and if needed prepend it:

   ```
   {% set url = entry.url | slice(0,4) == 'http' ? entry.url : 'http://' ~ entry.url %}
   ```

Be sure to use the {% cache %} tag if you use option 2, so the check only has to be done once.

Edit: You could use [this plugin](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/link-field) to pre-validate your urls.

Comment: The {% cache %} tag is going to force a database call on every request to retrieve the cached item. It'll probably be faster to just let Twig/PHP do the processing each time.

Comment: True. Didn't think about that. Don't be angry, Brad.

Comment: I'm only angry when I'm sober.

Comment: That Twig template ternary totally toppled my tribulations. Thanks!

Comment: @shanecavaliere: I suggest you use the plugin, as that twig-code doesn't really validate. If your client messes up somehow, let's say miss an h at the start, the url will end up as http://ttp://url.com.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fieldtype called [Link](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/link-field) from Sprout that validates links, and it works very well.

One point of criticism is that the error it gives you when you haven't added the protocol isn't very client-friendly. It just says: 'Link must be a valid link.'

You could either contact Sprout and give them feedback on that, and they'll probably improve it (it's in beta), or you could modify it yourself.